# Blocking directory access with link

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, directory

I am building a website that has a lot of nested elements so I disabled the access to the directory listings with  Options -Indexes in .htaccess but it then throws me the forbidden message (which is good because it works) but I'd like to disable the directory listing by making a redirect to "#".

I just want the user to stay in the same page he was looking if he tries to sneak into my directories...is that possible somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ %{HTTP_REFERER}# [R,L,NE]
```

after you re-enable indexes.